# Specify opencv with CMAKE_ARGS in conda yml

Tags: opencv, conda

How can I specify conda (in the `environment.yml`) to install `opencv-contrib-python` with pip while specifying `CMAKE_ARGS`.

Basically, how can I specify conda to run this command in the `environment.yml` file

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON" pip install --no-binary=opencv-contrib-python opencv-contrib-python
```

As it stands if I export the environment via `conda env export > environment.yml`, it just specifies the version of opencv like so

```
name: test
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - pkgs/main
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - Bunch of conda dependencies
  - pip:
    - opencv-contrib-python==4.5.1.48
prefix: /home/an/miniconda3/envs/test
```

Comment: You should be able to add the `--no-binary` argument to the line specifying opencv-contrib-python, but as for the CMAKE_ARGS, that would need to be set in the shell when running the creation - no way to do it *in the YAML* - e.g., `CMAKE_ARGS="..." conda env create -f environment.yml`.

Comment: Thanks @merv. If this is indeed the case and you're sure there's no way this can be done, can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Conda v4.9 did add an option](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) to manage environment variables in active environments via YAML, these are not set during environment creation. Hence, there is no way to set the `CMAKE_ARGS` during environment creation through the YAML.

The rest of the `pip install` command can be added:

```yaml
name: test
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults  # note that 'main' is a subset of defaults
dependencies:
  # - Bunch of conda dependencies
  - pip
  - pip:
    - --no-binary=opencv-contrib-python
    - opencv-contrib-python
```

and instead set the `CMAKE_ARGS` when invoking:

```bash
CMAKE_ARGS="-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON" conda env create -f environment.yml
```